# How to copy [just] the alignment and the indentation?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, indentation, alignment

If i have many paragraphs and i want to  `(Format paint)` **just** ***the alignment and the indentation*** of the first paraghragh to the others without other styles like the font and colors how to do that ?

for Example :

---

[image]

---

i want the alignment and the indentation of all paragraphs like the first one ?

Answer (score 0):

Format painter is used to copy full formatting from one range of text to another, I doubt there is any way to copy only certain attributes. The fastest procedure is to just check the values of the first paragraph and manually set them on the other paragraphs (highlight multiple non-contiguous paragraphs using CTRL) in one quick go.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want to have to manually change the paragraph format 30 times in the same document.

Comment: @ponder275, You can highlight non contiguous paragraphs by holding CTRL, so in essence setting the format for these paragraph would be a single operation and likely much faster than any other work around.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is *exactly* what you're looking for, but it's better than Format Painter as far as preserving italics and some other formatting items. Note that I've only tested this with Word 2010.

What you want to do is create a new Style.

So in your example, you would highlight the reference for Miller in its entirety, then select the dropdown icon in Styles on the Home tab. From there you'll select "Save selection as New Quick Style..." which brings up a window to name your new style. Select "Modify..." to confirm that the settings are what you want, and select OK to create the Style.

Then just highlight the items you want to change, and select your new Style from the Styles menu.

As an aside, it appears you're doing technical or thesis writing, and [LaTex](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/learn/free-online-introduction-to-latex-part-1) can make your life a lot easier for that kind of work.